# string matching problem?

Tags: java, string, matching

i want to parse a textfile. if ":" occurs then i want to split the array in two pieces. the second piece gets investigated further: if it contains "in " (note the space, this is important) or "out " the arraylist ports gets populated. if neither "in " nor "out " is in the second half of the original string, generics gets populated. i tried it with the following code:

```
if (str.matches("\\:")) {
  String[] splitarray = str.split("\\:");
  if (splitarray[1].matches("in ")) {
    ports.add(str);
  } else {  
    if (splitarray[1].matches("out ")) {
      ports.add(str);
    } else {
      generics.add(str);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That backslash is wrong - it introduces a special character, which : is not.  If you want to escape a special regex character then you need a double backslash.  : isn't a special regex character so you don't need it at all.

Comment: can you not use [java.util.Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

`matches` determines if the whole String matches the expression, not if some part of the string matches the expression. For such a simple case, I wouldn't go with regexp. Just use indexOf to find your substring:

```
int indexOfColon = str.indexOf(':');
if (indexOfColon >= 0) {
    String afterColon = str.substring(indexOfColon + 1);
    int indexOfIn = afterColon.indexOf("in ");
    // you get the idea
}
```

Comment: @Bart Kiers : since the OP wants the substring after the first colon found, using contains would search for the colon, and indexOf would then have to be used if contains returns true, which results to two searches instead of just one.

Comment: yeah, I didn't really read passed the `if` statement. In this case, `indexOf` would indeed be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // assuming only 1 occurence of ':'
    String a = "sasdads:asdadin ";
    ArrayList<String> ports = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> generics = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (a.contains(":")) {
        String[] strings = a.split(":");
        if (strings[1].contains("in ")) {
            ports.add(strings[1]);
        }else{
            generics.add(strings[1]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```